# Optional positioning parameter and tabularx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am normally typesetting small tables using the basic `tabular`environment. This has a optional parameter controlling the vertical position of the tabular with respect to the baseline of the surrounding text.
Now for some reason I needed switch to `tabularx`. However, here the optional position parameter is missing, so that now the center of the table is aligned with the baseline:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

A simple text
\begin{tabular}[b]{lr}
    A & B \\ C & D \\
\end{tabular}
and a little more
\begin{tabularx}{.1\linewidth}{lr}
    A & B \\ C & D \\
\end{tabularx}
and the rest.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea how I can achieve an alignment with the bottom of the table?

Comment: note you have no `X`  column in your `tabularx` so that can not work as a `tabularx`, it essentially falls back to being `tabular*` (but less efficient) every `tabularx` has to have at least one `X` column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is a MWE. I didnt need a X column here. Obviously, my use case is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularx` has the same parameter, as for `tabular*` it follows the width argument.

```
 \begin{tabularx}{3cm}[t]{XXX}
```

Early versions of the package documentation did not mention it but it has always had the argument.

Comment: Oh damn! I tried it, but *before* the length definition. And the package documentation on my system didn't mention it either.
Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Dux No the doc didn't mention it explicitly for a couple of decades, I did update it last year (I think) however it was implicitly documented as the arguments of `tabularx` were defined as being "the same as `tabular*`"  even in the earliest versions of the documentation.

Comment: I sure missed that...